# Data Sheet view issues

Tags: datasheet

I have a list with two views 1.data sheet view 2.standard view. users are able to edit datasheet view and standard view. The issue is when users want to edit Standard view in data sheet they are unable to edit it and gets an error like "An unexpected error has occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved." Please let me the know any solution if you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

users are not having correct permissions to the list. hence they are unable to edit the items in data sheet view.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of causes for this error, so here are a few different situations that may apply.

## Change the Columns

Try one of the following two methods:

1. Isolate the error by removing columns from the view one at a time until you find the column that is causing the issue.
2. [Remove special characters](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e99bcd20-14f7-445a-ac46-6a27696f1cb8/sharepoint-data-connection-error-an-unexpected-error-has-occured-changes-to-your-data-cannot-be?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) from the field name
3. [Undeclare as a record](http://blog.sharepointrx.com/2010/12/30/cant-update-record-in-datasheet-view/)

## Patch

For SharePoint 2007, there is a hotfix available that applies to that error:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958695

For SharePoint 2010, it's been reported that [Service Pack 1 addresses some issues](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/974b9168-f548-409b-a7f9-a79b9fdd4c50/datasheet-problems-after-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious) that may be related.

Comment: Hi Tom,I tried to install above KB article but got "There are no products affected by this package installed on this system".

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Comment: The hotfix I referenced above addresses the  "An unexpected error has occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved." issue for SharePoint 2007. It should already be a part of 2010. Are the columns shown in both of your views the same?

Comment: Standard view is having just 40% of the fields/columns of Data sheet view. on Standard view I have a look up field which is not present on Data sheet view.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the fields in the datasheet view one by one until you've found the culprit.

Comment: Tom, actually it is due to improper permissions for the list. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Glad you found the answer! That is a tricky one.